# iOS dynamic addition of UIControls

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to add a bunch of UIButtons to a screen at runtime. Based on user input I want to show different buttons in different locations. Is this possible?

Comment: Translation: "Is creating UI elements in code possible?"  Yes, of course it is!

Comment: That's not my question. I'm asking whether you can create a button without declaring it in the header as you normally do if you were going to do it in code. Actually dynamic.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "declaring it in the header".

Comment: I think he meant `.h` file, but yes you can create buttons on runtime. But you've to mention the `buttonWithType` and `frame` though and add it as a `subView`, one of the user has already answered. You can run them in a for loop to have `n` number of buttons, don't worry about the memory issue `buttonWithType` uses autorelease.

Comment: The interface. Usually to add a UIButton programmatically you'd create a UIButton property in the interface, synthesize it in the implementation and then add it to the view. I've almost got it working as per Brian's snippet. Just trying to figure out how to know which button was pressed now...

Comment: Well, assuming that is the case, you don't need an instance variable for any button (it is *not* in fact normal) unless you need an explicit reference to a particular button for some reason.  You just need to create it and add it to the view hierarchy as Brian said.

Comment: Which button is pressed?  Use its `tag` property! ;)

Comment: ah, go figure. I thought the way I was doing it was dumb... Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Creating a button in objective-C:

```
UIButton *btnPrefix = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnPrefix setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[btnPrefix setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
[btnPrefix addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview: btnPrefix];
```